# Text file to 2d array, then search for the user ID,change just that one line, and reprint text file with the change done

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, split

this is what the text file is the final digit is the ID. it is for a mock atm machine.the id is brought in threw a text file. So I need to search the file for the final number then change just that line.then reprint the text file. I am new to C# and coding and any help would be appreciated.
user1,1111,1000.00,15000.00,1
user2,2222,2000.00,25000.00,2
user3,3333,3000.00,35000.00,3

```
        int i = 0, 
        int j = 0;
        string[,] result = new string[3, 5];//call the 2d array
        foreach (var row in file.Split('\n'))//split file into the rows or lines
        {
            j = 0;
            foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(','))//split the ,.
            {
                result[i, j] = Convert.ToString(col.Trim());
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        int b = 0;
        while(b<3)
        {
            if (id == result[b, 5])//looking for the number from id in result.
            {
                result[b, 2] = cheq;//change the proper place with a variable that works from another text file
                result[b, 3] = save;//change the proper place with a variable that works from another text file

            }
            b++;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(result[2,3]);
```

this is all done in forms in visual studio I am getting an exceptions error pop up  index was outside the bounds of the array. If there is a better way to do all this I am all ears. I am a student and the goal is to save the changes the person made while in the atm machine to a text file when they press exit.

Comment: Right here:  id == result[b, 5]  But your array has indexes 0 to 4.  So 5 is out of bounds

Comment: From a quick glance, you're code to parse the file looks OK, but there are a couple of obvious errors in the loop to look through the records. Firstly you only increment 'b' if you find a match, so that loop will run forever if there are less than 3 matching records. Also, the input file has 5 fields, so they will be numbered 0 through 4, so if (id == result[b, 5]) will throw an out of bounds error.

Comment: thank you, i changed the if statement to 4 , moved the b++ to the proper location but I still get the same error. Can it be the message box won't show a 2d array even if im pointing at a specific spot.

Comment: At this point, what you need to do is step through the code and examine all the variables (and important expressions) at each step along the way. As a student, learning how to debug is extremely important and will save you many precious hours and plenty of SO questions.